# Spark cluster - Stuck at start-all.sh and stop-all.sh

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

I am trying to configure a spark cluster, where I have one driver and one executor. After having done all the necessary setup, I am trying to start my cluster using the scripts in `.../spark/sbin`, namely start-all.sh.

The script is able to start the master and get stuck after the output starting worker. In one of the runs, it gave out a ssh connection time out error. How can I solve this problem ?

Passwordless ssh from driver to executor is already set up and is working fine when I manually ssh into the executor.

The cluster UI, shows that the worker/executor is alive. But when I submit a job to the cluster, I get an error :

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Comment: Look at the logs produced by hadoop. They can given insights as to what is happening.